# Issue Connecting to facebook using facebookclient object with access_token

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to retrieve the posts from my facebook graph api Users wall.
The code I have implemented is as follows.

```
try 
{
    FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("123406454567|hEcTbdascdfffffa1e334gf");
    Connection<Post> posts = facebookClient.fetchConnection(""+id+"/posts", Post.class);//id=app-user-id
    java.util.List<Post> list;
    list = posts.getData();
    for(Post p:list)
    {
        System.out.println(p.getDescription());
    }
} 
catch (FacebookException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I retrieved the access_token for my app using the link:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=***&client_secret=***
```

I get a warning:

> 2012-02-16 17:35:28.291:WARN::/
>           java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
>               at com.restfb.DefaultWebRequestor.(DefaultWebRequestor.java:73)
>               at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.(DefaultFacebookClient.java:119)
>               at com.akaara.se.fb.FacebookCallbackHandler$FacebookCallbackHandlerDelegate.handleHttpPost(FacebookCallbackHandler.java:98)
>               at com.akaara.se.fb.FacebookCallbackHandler$FacebookCallbackHandlerDelegate.handle(FacebookCallbackHandler.java:49)
>               at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>               at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>               at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>               at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:943)
>               at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
>               at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
>               at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>               at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
>               at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

From this I can understand That access_token is the issue.
Im pretty new to this.
can anyone help me with this?
Thanks In Advance.

I Have Included log4j.jar to my build path.

Comment: Umm, from the warning message it kind of seems that the DefaultWebRequestor is trying to use a class that is not present in your path.  Try adding the apache log4j library to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Your warning is related to log4j, a library used for logging. To make the warning go away, you need to download the library from [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) and add it to your program.

When you downloaded the library you are using to connect to Facebook, it either carried this dependency with it or stated that it was needed for it to function properly. There might be other dependencies that are also required by the library you are using, I would recommend checking that to make sure you are not missing anything.

Comment: Thanks.
I had already included Log4j.jar to my build path.
Issue still exists :(

Comment: But is it included in our classpath when running the Java process? That's where it needs to be.

Comment: Im running this using a threat. And yes I have added this to our classpath .
now the warning seems to be gone.
Thanks.
but there an other issue.
I had created a java class file named "fb.FaceBookMessageReceiver", then after a while i deleted it.
But I get a warning :

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.akaara.se.fb.FaceBookMessageReceiver
Why is that..
Any suggestions ??

Comment: James: Not really this time. Why did you delete the class file? I usually never delete class files manually.

Answer (score 0):

go to log4j in apache.org

download the jar and include it in your project.

Basically it is complaining that you are missing the Logger class that can be found in the log4j package. There may be other issues in your program, but this is what this warning/error is complaining about.